# How to post nested JSON data in Android?

Tags: java, android, json

I need to post the below JSON data from Android to a Webservice. This is JSON data

> {"AutoMobileName":"Mercedes","Engine":"V4","BrandInfo":{"Model":"C500","ColorType"
>   : "Black","DatePurchased":"1990"}}

Using Android Java i am doing like this.

```
JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
holder.put("AutoMobileName", "Mercedes");
holder.put("Engine", "V4");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
httpost.setEntity(se);
```

Using the above code, the two parameters gets posted , but how do i send the `BrandInfo` data as it nested.

How do i put it inside the `holder` object and post it ?

Comment: @Nambi..you could try List & HashMap for this . It could be quite easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
     JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();

    //BrandInfo
    JSONObject brandInfo = new JSONObject();
    brandInfo.put("Model", "C500");
    brandInfo.put("ColorType", "Black");
    brandInfo.put("DatePurchased", "1990");


    holder.put("AutoMobileName", "Mercedes");
    holder.put("Engine", "V4");
    holder.put("BrandInfo", brandInfo);
    System.out.println(holder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another json object for brand info

```
JSONObject brandInfo = new JSONObject();
brandInfo.put("Model","C500");
brandInfo.put("ColorType","Black");
brandInfo.put("DatePurchased","1990");
```

and assign it to the holder variable as follows :

```
JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
holder.put("AutoMobileName", "Mercedes");
holder.put("Engine", "V4");
holder.put("BrandInfo", brandInfo);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
httpost.setEntity(se);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject innerholder = new JSONObject();
    innerholder .put("Model", "C500");
    innerholder .put("ColorType", "Black");
    innerholder .put("DatePurchased", "1990");

    holder.put("BrandInfo", innerholder);
    holder.put("AutoMobileName", "Mercedes");
    holder.put("Engine", "V4");


StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
httpost.setEntity(se);
```